# Magento 2 - Frontend Controller conditional based 404 page

Tags: magento2, frontend, url, controllers, 404-page

I have custom frontend controller, I added the URL Rewrite for this controller

I want to figure out the way, How I send requesting URL to `404 page` based on some condition within the controller.

I don't want the `noroute` redirect solution because it change the URL. For example if you disable the product, URL remain same but it goes to `404 page` and also I don't want to remove the URL Rewrite for this controller as well.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is valid according to best practices but following also works for me:

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
```

and

```
public function execute()
{
    ...
    if (something) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Page Not Found'));
    }
    ...
}
```